# Is there any way to remove BatchToSpaceND from tf.layers.conv1d?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

As I get, tf.layers.conv1d uses pipeline like this: BatchToSpaceND -> conv1d -> SpaceToBatchND. So the question is how to remove (or disable) BatchToSpaceND and SpaceToBatchND from the pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've investigated it's impossible to remove BatchToSpaceND and SpaceToBatchND from tf.layers.conv1d without changing and rebuilding tensorflow source code. One of the solutions is to replace layers to tf.nn.conv1d, which is low-level representation of convolutional layers (in fact tf.layers.conv1d is a wrapper around tf.nn.conv1d). These low-level implementations doesn't include BatchToSpaceND and SpaceToBatchND.